# Dashboard for Websphere Instance or JVM status with HTML and php

Tags: websphere, dashboard, websphere-8, websphere-7

Am not getting the perfect answer for my requirement. Please find the detailed requirement in Lyman English.

I have an application which is installed in Websphere Application Server 8.5 version.

Got a requirement for me to create a dashboard where in we can see the server status like whether the JVM is up or down, EAR deployed date etc.

Dashboard needs to be accessed from Internet explorer on Windows Desktop.

Could you let me know how to achieve this?

Note: Websphere is installed on Linux and IE is on Windows.

Thanks,
Nithin

Answer (score 0):

This is quite broad question, so I'll just give you options that you will have to explore further by your own and choose the one that suits you best.
From the easiest one:

1. Use built-in admin console - WebSphere provides admin gui, if you dont want to allow users to change anything just give the user monitor role. He will be able to check server status, application status etc...
2. Use monitoring tool already available, like IBM Health Center, JConsole or 3rd party - I know, not the browser solution but maybe will fit your need
3. Install and use [PerfServlet](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSAW57_8.5.5/com.ibm.websphere.nd.doc/ae/tprf_devprfservlet.html) - it will give you WebSphere statistics in XML format. You can write your app to query that servlet for required params, then parse and present output
4. Finally use MBean API and write your custom monitoring app - the most difficult but also the most flexible.

Looking at your question, I'd suggest you to stay with option 1).